# How to index logs for ELK stack usage (using documents on elastic search)

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, log4j, logstash, elastic-stack

I have an ELK stack running where the logstash listens on port 5000 and my application is using log4j to write to socket which the logstash listens to.
I'm trying to be able to log request/response/update after then to be able to query the logs.
The log looks something like the following:

**time stamp,uuid,reqeust/response/update (type of the log),the json body**

2017-09-19T14:29Z,b610d7ae-eef7-42a2-8c0a-4e2c94f06fcc,RESPONSE,{"serverIp":"127.0.0.1","**rule**":30085,"version":49973,"quoteId":"a7c716fc-c046-4460-adec-8078936c603f","param1":1999.139102677809,"param2":5000.0}

what is the best practice so i be able to query let's say for example all logs with specific **rule** (i have also bold the rule in the log so you be able to understand that i'm talking on the same rule from the log entry)

also should i write the log in a different better convention?

Comment: Have you met grok{}?

Comment: @Alain Collins can you elaborate more please

Comment: Have you done anything to parse your unstructured data into structured fields that would then be inserted into elasticsearch (and thus queryable)?